# ¿Cómo puedo fragmentar un archivo de texto demasiado grande?

Tags: python, split

Estoy tratando de dividir un archivo de texto con más de 1,000 ejercicios en 10 archivos con extensión .txt.
Sí me ha pasado de hacer esos 10 archivos por separado, pero quiero saber cómo se puede fragmentar un archivo grande en otras partes. Investigué `split`, pero el ejemplo que vi no hace lo de fragmentar un archivo en otros más pequeños.

Por ejemplo, quiero dividir esto:

```
insert1=int(input('Valor: '))#Suponiendo que insert1 vale 10,000
archivo=open('Numeración.txt', 'w')
for i in range(1, insert1):
    archivo.write(f'{i}.-\n')
archivo.close()
```

El ejemplo del método `split` que encontré fue este:

```
txt = "welcome to the jungle"
x = txt.split()
print(x)
```

¿Hay alguna forma de dividir el archivo de texto con el método de `split` o alguna función de python?
Agradezco su apoyo!

Comment: ¿Quieres dividir un archivo en partes sin importar que un ejercicio quede dividido? Hay muchos utilitarios para todas las plataformas que te permiten hacerlo. Busca "como dividir un archivo en partes".

Comment: Pero quiero hacerlo yo mismo en python, no quiero que una plataforma me automatice el proceso. Aunque si lo pensamos bien, en cierto modo python hace el trabajo. Pero el punto es que quiero saber cómo se hace.

Comment: Me gusta tu actitud. Dale. Un primer método sería leer el archivo de entrada linea por linea, e ir grabando en un archivo de salida, a la vez que sumas los largos de cada línea grabada. Cuando llegas a un limite, cierras el archivo de salida y sigues con otro,.

Comment: Se me ocurrió así: `archivo=open('Numeradores2.txt', 'w')`
`with open(b"C:\Users\youna\Desktop\Numeradores.txt") as f:`
    `data = f.readlines()[0:100]`
    `archivo.write(f'{data}')`
`archivo.close()`

Comment: Pero se añade como listas y además lee el salto del línea `\n` pero no logro automatizarlo. Se me ocurre hacer un ciclo for para automatizarlo tomando en cuenta la cantidad de líneas y dividirlo entre la cantidad de txt, que quiera

Comment: Tienes que leer y grabar linea por linea. Usa un `for linea in f:`. Tendras la línea completa (incluyendo el '\n' al final)

Comment: Muchas gracias @CandidMoe por ahí iban los tiros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si a alguien le llegase a servir le dejo el código que encontré en otro hilo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289859/splitting-large-text-file-into-smaller-text-files-by-line-numbers-using-python

```
lines_per_file = 300
smallfile = None
with open('Numeracion.txt') as bigfile:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(bigfile):
        if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
            if smallfile:
                smallfile.close()
            small_filename = 'Numeracion{}.txt'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
            smallfile = open(small_filename, "w")
        smallfile.write(line)
    if smallfile:
        smallfile.close()
```

Comment: Si el código te ha solucionado el problema puedes marcarlo como respuesta aceptada, aunque sea tuya. Así el próximo que tenga ese mismo problema sabrá que ese código le puede servir.